# IntelliJ run TestNG tests in 1 directory

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I have separated my unit and integration tests into separate IntelliJ "Test Sources" directories.  When I right-click on my unit test folder and attempt to run those tests, the integration tests get roped in as well.

I would ultimately like to be able to right-click on my unit test folder and have only the tests under that folder run and the same for integration tests.

Is there a way to do this in IntelliJ or am I going to have to use a testng.xml file to accomplish this?

Comment: I think this feature is not available out of the box and you should ask for it on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: @JulienHerr - good idea...I have submitted a feature request

Answer (score 2):

How about using 2 [test groups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) and creating 2 run configurations, 1 for unit testing and 1 for integration testing:

**1)** Some dummy test class that simulates both categories

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CategoryTests {

    @Test(groups = "unit")
    public void someUnitTest(){

    }

    @Test(groups = "integration")
    public void someIntegrationTest(){

    }
}
```

**2)** Unit test IJ run config (notice the Group setup)

[image: Unit test config]

**3)** Integration test IJ run config (again, notice the Group setup)

[image: Integration test config]

**4)** All in one sample

[image: TestNG categories]

Comment: I could do that but then I have to add every test to some group.  If it ends up that I have to go that way, so be it, but I believe it would be very useful for me (and other developers) to be able to just right click on a folder and run the tests that are only in that folder instead of having to specify a group on each test.  I believe this can be done using JUnit and IntelliJ but not TestNG at the moment...

Comment: @ZackMacomber Hmm, what about having different packages rather than different sources?! That way you could use `All in package` or `Pattern` instead of `Group` in the run configuration. Any particular reason why you chose 2 source folders?!

Comment: Not a bad idea...I might just group by package rather than having separate source folders...guess I wanted to just have a clean separation between int and unit tests and also wanted to put tests in the packages that correspond with their corresponding prod package